# redirect URI in Azure web app authentication

Tags: azure

I have browsed various questions here on SO, but none seem to have helped.

So, I have the following setup on Azure. I had a simple flask app running, which I could access using `https://xyz.azurewebsites.net`.

I was trying to look at the example here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=linux). I can reproduce this example fine when I have the local server running and specifying the redirect uri as `http://localhost:5000/getAToken`.

Now, I want to use my deployed app, so I changed the redirect URI in the azure portal under authentication as

`https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/getAToken`

However, this always returns the redirect URI mismatch error.

On the flask side, I have kept the configuration as:

```
REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"
```

Although I tried putting the full absolute URL as well and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the same document which you have provided and able to access the Application even after deploying to `Azure App Service`.

In `app_config.py`, change the `authority_template` to

```cs
authority_template = "https://{b2c_tenant}.b2clogin.com/{b2c_tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{signupsignin_user_flow}"
```

***OR***

- Copy paste the `tenant` and `user_flow` value directly.

```cs
authority_template  =  "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{user_flow}"
```

***Local Output:***
[image]

***Deploy the Application to Azure App Service:***

- Create a new repository in GitHub and push the `VSCode` to it.

***OR***
If you face any issues in pushing the code to Git.

- Create a new repository, copy and clone the [application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp) which you have provided.

[image]

***Your Repository:***
[image]

- And change the values in `app_config.py` accordingly (from your local `VSCode`).
- In `Azure Portal` => Create a new `App Service` with Run time Stack `Python`.

[image]

- From `Deployment center` => Deploy the code using `GitHub Actions`.

[image]

- Add the Redirect URI of the deployed Application in App registration.

```cs
https://YourDeployedAppName.azurewebsites.net/getAToken
```

Here my deployed app name is `myadb2c`.So, update the Redirect URI as below.

```cs
https://myadb2c.azurewebsites.net/getAToken
```

[image]

***Workflow in GitHub Repository: ***
[image]

***Deployed Application Output:***

[image]

[image]